# Routing to a Typescript (.tsx) Class in React?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, routes

If I have my Login.tsx

```
export class Login {
...
```

and in my App.tsx I try to:

```
<BrowserRouter>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Login />}></Route>
```

But I cant put  since it isn't a .jsx class. I tried {Login}, doesn't work. Do you know what to do?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UXd1p.png)

Comment: You are exporting a class from Login.tsx and trying to use it as a React component. That is not going to work. Try using it as a class only. If you still want to use Login as a React component export a function from Login.tsx which returns React elements.

Comment: I turned it into a function: export const Login = () => {
I have no errors inside my code, but the console is giving me 

Warning: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. 
and ...
TypeError: dispatcher is null

Comment: Can you add the instance of file in which you are getting the error.

Comment: I entered a link of the console output. it doesn't give me an explicit class :(